# How to link Python C module with `ld`. undefined reference to `__dso_handle'

Tags: python, linux, ld

My current command:

```
c++ -fPIC -c algo_cython.cpp
ld -shared algo_cython.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 -lc -lstdc++   -o algo_cython.so
```

And the error:

```
algo_cython.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
algo_cython.cpp:(.text+0x83e4): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
ld: algo_cython.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

Comment: Can you show the compilation commands used to generate algo_cython.o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile `algo_cython.cpp` using the option `-fPIC` - you can't compile a shared object in 64bit on intel without this flag, so the line for compiling should read:

```
c++ -fPIC -c algo_cython.cpp
```

Additionally, I'd actually use the compiler-driver to produce the shared object, rather than directly calling `ld` i.e. you can use:

```
c++ -shared algo_cython.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 -lc -lstdc++   -o algo_cython.so
```

Unless you **really** want to do something that can't be driven from the compiler driver, directly invoking `ld` is not what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, I already had `-fPIC`. Why should I not call `ld` directly? And how would it look like to call it directly?

Comment: Also, it still doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error at linking, but when I try to import that Python module, I get `undefined symbol: init_csage_module`.

Comment: Ok, that last error was Sage-specific. (You had to link against `libcsage.so`.)

Comment: Re first comment: because it generally misses something you need to link against to get it to work (like core libraries). Re second comment: your module depends on sagelib?

Comment: Sure it misses something. That is why I asked here about what exactly was missing. Not really depends, but I uses its headers because it is used inside Sage.

Comment: as an example, if you use the compiler driver for linking it automatically adds the c++ library without you needing to put it on the link-line you can see what the driver adds by using the `-###` option to the final compile line - it implicitly adds the `-L` option as well as the `-lc` and `-lstdc++` options… less to remember to type == less chance of missing something